# Two methods for loading jobs

Tags: python, comparative-review

I am wondering which method code is more "Pythonic":

```
def load_job(self, identifier, job_name):
    i = 5
    ex = None
    while i:
        try:
            for ep in iter_entry_points(group='core.account', name=identifier):
                self.modules[identifier] = ep
            # load_entry_point(ep.dist, 'core.account', ep.name)
            # The following is the same
            loaded = ep.load()
            job = getattr(loaded, job_name)
            return job
        except ImportError as e:
            ex = e
            i -= 1
            time.sleep(2)
            continue

    raise ex
```

Or

```
def load_job(self, identifier, job_name):

    i = 5
    job = None
    ex = None
    while i:
        try:
            for ep in iter_entry_points(group='core.account', name=identifier):
                self.modules[identifier] = ep
                # load_entry_point(ep.dist, 'core.account', ep.name)
                # The following is the same
                loaded = ep.load()
                self.info("Loaded %s", ep.module_name)
                job = getattr(loaded, job_name)

            break
        except ImportError as er:
            ex = er
            i -= 1
            time.sleep(2)

    if job:
        return job
    else:
        raise ex
```

While the later is a bit longer, I feel it's easier to read. My main concern is whether I should `return` or `break` from within the `while` loop.

Comment: Why do you only want the last `job`? Why do you use a `while` loop instead of `for`?

Comment: @jonsharpe, there should be only one job, because identifier is unique. I just didn't want to use for embedded in another for loop.

Comment: This won't even run - `e` is not in scope after the loop.

Comment: The `for` loop in the first example is not indented that same way as the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering which method code is more "Pythonic":

Neither is more or less Pythonic than the other.

There's a different issue to consider here,
that of scope.

The first approach has a problem here:

> ```
>         for ep in iter_entry_points(group='core.account', name=identifier):
>             self.modules[identifier] = ep
>         loaded = ep.load()
> ```

When you set `loaded`,
the variable `ep` might not be unset.
Even if *you know* that there will be at least one iterations and therefore the variable will be always set, this is not a good practice.
It would be better to set a default value before the `for` loop.

The second approach doesn't have this problem.
But it has another weakness.
The `job` variable has a longer *live-time*:
it's defined before the `while` loop and used after it.
Ideally it's best to minimize the live-time of variables as much as possible.

Finally, both approaches would benefit from changing the `while` loop to a `for` loop.
The advantage of a `for` loop over a `while` loop is that it naturally limits the scope of the loop variable `i` to the loop's body.
Which is a good thing,
as it eliminates the possibility of the loop variable ever getting accidentally used outside the loop's body.

Answer (score 3):

There are three things wrong with the while loop.

1. You are looping over a fixed number of times. The only other way to leave the loop is a `return` statement. This is exactly what a `for` loop is for. A `while` loop is used when the number of times the loop needs to execute is not known ahead of time. You should use the right tool for the job.
2. Don't use the truth value of a value when you can very easily explicitly state what you want the break condition to be. There are two advantages to using `i > 0` is better than what you have. First, it is much easier for the reader. What you have forces the reader to think about what `i` is, how it might be equivalent to `False`, and how the loop has to manipulate `i` to reach that condition. Secondly, you can accidentally cause an infinite loop if you are not properly manipulating `i`. If you accidentally double decrement `i` when it is equal to 1, then while clause will evaluate to `True` when it checks `-1`. This will not happen when you are explicit about when you want the looping to continue.
3. In the first example, the last line of the loop is `continue`. This serves no purpose. There is no code that would be executed otherwise if the `continue` was omitted. Since it is the last line, the next thing that would happen would be to evaluate the while clause. That is the same thing a `continue` will trigger.

**Edit**:

With respect to the actual question, I think returning is fine. The seconds example is an attempt to follow the [single return pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36707/210526). However, the first implementation still only has one return statement. The only other way to exit the method is by having an exception raised. The `try` block is the main body of the method. Everything else is the retry functionality.

Comment: I find your comments helpful, but my original question still stands: should return or break from within the  loop?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a [`timeout` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish) or function, and a `get_job` function. That would greatly simplify your code:

```
@timeout(10, 2)
def get_job(identifier, job_name)
```